# AWS sync to deploy only new or updated files to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, github-actions, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I've written a Github actions script that takes files from a folder `migrations` and uploads it to s3. The problem with this pipeline is that all other files in the directory also get updated. How can I go about only updating new or updated files?
Here's the current script as it stands.

```
name: function-name
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: eu-central-1
      - name: Deploy file to s3
        run: aws s3 sync ./migration/ s3://s3_bucket
```

Comment: That's what `aws s3 sync` does: it copies new and updated files. Are you saying that it's re-uploading files that were unchanged (and have the same timestamp as the original)?

Comment: Yes, When I add a new file is added on GitHub, the last modified timestamp for all the files on S3 changes to when the last file was uploaded.

Comment: At a guess, you are actually cloning the repo locally causing all local timestamps to be set to 'now' and then attempting to sync the files to S3.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the GitHub Action [`jakejarvis/s3-sync-action`](https://github.com/jakejarvis/s3-sync-action), which uses the [vanilla AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/index.html) to sync a directory (either from your repository or generated during your workflow) with a remote S3 bucket.

It is based on [aws s3 `sync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html), which should enable an incremental backup, instead of copying/modifying every files.

Add as "`source_dir`" the `migration` folder

```yaml
  steps:
  ...
    - uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
      with:
        args: --acl public-read --follow-symlinks --delete
      env:
        AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET }}
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        AWS_REGION: 'us-west-1'   # optional: defaults to us-east-1
        SOURCE_DIR: 'migration'   # optional: defaults to entire repository
```

However, [taseenb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/950704/taseenb) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70557361/aws-sync-to-deploy-only-new-or-updated-files-to-s3/70574047?noredirect=1#comment125613069_70574047):

> This does not work as intended (like an incremental backup).
>
> `S3 sync cli` command will copy all files every time when run inside a GitHub Action.
> I believe this happens when we clone the repository inside a Docker image to execute the operation (this is what [`jakejarvis/s3-sync-action`](https://github.com/jakejarvis/s3-sync-action) does).
>
> I don't think there is a perfect solution using S3 sync.
>
> But if you are sure that your files always change size you can use `--size-only` in the args.
> It will ignore files with the same size, so probably not safe in most cases.

Comment: This does not work as intended (like an incremental backup). S3 `sync` cli command will copy all files every time when run inside a Github Action. I believe this happens when we clone the repository inside a Docker image to execute the operation (this is what `jakejarvis/s3-sync-action` does).

Comment: @taseenb That is unfortunate. Did you find any other solution?

Comment: Hey, I don't think there is a perfect solution using S3 sync. But if you are sure that your files always change size you can use `--size-only` in the args. It will ignore files with the same size so probably not safe in most cases.

Comment: @taseenb Good feedback, thank you. I have included your comments in the answer for more visibility.